# Need to trim last character string only if is blank or "."

Tags: r

I have a large vector of words read from an excel file. Some of those records end with space or "." period.  Only in those cases, I need to trim those chars.

Example:

```
"depresion"                              "tristeza."                             
"nostalgia"                              "preocupacion."                         
"enojo."                                 "soledad "                              
"frustracion"                            "desesperacion "                        
"angustia."                              "desconocidos."
```

Notice some words end normal without "." or " ".

Is there a way to do that?

I have this

```
substr(conceptos, 1, nchar(conceptos)-1))
```

to test for the last character  (conceptos is this long vector)

Thanks for any advise,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more `.` or spaces and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("(\\.| )*$", "", v1)
#[1] "depresion"     "tristeza"      "nostalgia"     "preocupacion"  "enojo"   
#[6] "soledad"       "frustracion"   "desesperacion"
#[9] "angustia"      "desconocidos"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("depresion","tristeza.","nostalgia","preocupacion.",
   "enojo.","soledad ","frustracion","desesperacion ",
   "angustia.","desconocidos.")
```

Comment: Also `sub("[. ]+$", "", x)`

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are good for this:

```
library(stringr)

x = c("depresion", "tristeza.", "nostalgia", "preocupacion.", 
      "enojo.", "soledad ", "frustracion", "desesperacion ", 
      "angustia.", "desconocidos.")
x_replaced = str_replace(x, "(\\.|\\s)$", "")
```

The pattern `(\\.|\\s)$` will match a `.` or any whitespace that occurs right at the end of the string.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

iif((mid(trim(conceptos), Len(conceptos), 1) == ".") ? substr(conceptos, 1, nchar(conceptos)-1)) : trim(conceptos))